# Determine which fragment is showing to update

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am updating the view that is currently showing and I Hide/Show two fragments.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (mTaxLocationListViewFrag.isVisible()) {
        if (mGoogleMapFrag == null) {
            mGoogleMapFrag = new GoogleMapFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, mGoogleMapFrag);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.hide(mListViewFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.show(mGoogleMapFrag).commit();

    } else {fragmentTransaction.hide(mGoogleMapFrag).show(mListViewFrag).commit();
    }

    updateDisplay();
```

updateDisplay method-

```
if (mListViewFrag != null && mListViewFrag.isVisible()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Update Location ListView");
            mListViewFrag.setLocations(mLocations);
        }

        if (mGoogleMapFrag != null && mGoogleMapFrag.isVisible()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Update Google Maps Markers");
            //Convert locations to markers to display.

        }
```

The problem is I am guessing `fragmentTransaction` is asynchronous when performing `.show` and `.hide` and updateDisplay does not work properly as the it thinks the fragment to be hidden is still showing. Is there a more reliable way to check for which fragment to update?

Comment: Try adding fragmentTransaction.executePendingTransactions() after adding the fragment.

Comment: @Piyush that seems to have done it. If you want to add as solution. I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `fragmentTransaction.executePendingTransactions()` after adding the fragment. From the docs of [executePendingTransactions()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions()):

> It is scheduled to be executed asynchronously on the process's main thread.
>   If you want to immediately executing any such pending operations, you
>   can call this function (only from the main thread) to do so. Note that
>   all callbacks and other related behavior will be done from within this
>   call, so be careful about where this is called from.